# Sorting text inputs into an array for concise async storage code

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, textinput, asyncstorage

I have the following code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');

  // Async storage for input1

  const storeData = async (value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('input1', value)
    } catch (e) {
      // Saving error
    }
  }

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('input1')
      if(value !== null) {
        // Value previously stored
        setInput1(value)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      // Error reading value
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => { 
    storeData(input1)
  },[input1])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>Text</Text>
        <Text>{'\n'}</Text>

        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => setInput1(text)}
          value={input1}
          placeholder="Add text here"
        />

        <Text>{'\n'}</Text>

        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => setInput2(text)}
          value={input2}
          placeholder="Add text here"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I need to keep the code concise and I don't want to have multiple lots of this async storage code for each text input. In this example I only have two but I want to have many more. How do I sort these text inputs into an array and store them with only one lot of this async storage code? Thanks

**Edit:**

```
const [mon1, setMon1] = useState('');
  const [tue1, setTue1] = useState('');
  const [wed1, setWed1] = useState('');
  const [thu1, setThu1] = useState('');
  const [fri1, setFri1] = useState('');
  const [sat1, setSat1] = useState('');
  const [sun1, setSun1] = useState('');
  const [keys, setKeys] = useState('');

  const storeData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch (e) {
      // Saving error
    }
  }

  const getData = async (key) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
      if(value !== null) {
        // Value previously stored
        setMon1(value)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      // Error reading value
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => { 
    storeData(keys[keys.length-1],mon1)
  },[mon1])
```

```
<TextInput
 style={styles.cellText}
 onChangeText={(text) => {
 setMon1(text);
 setKeys(prev=>[...prev,`input${keys.length}`])
 }}
 value={mon1}
 placeholder="Tap to add tasks!"
 underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
 maxLength={70}
 multiline
 numberOfLines={4}
/>
```

Comment: I suggest using an object rather than an array, so that you can bind the `TextInput`s to the properties. Then you can just have a single `saveInput` function that save the object to asyncStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Pass one more parameter while storing and retrieving data.
Here is the example.

```js
const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);
```

we need this for storing all the keys.

```js
const storeData = async (value, key) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch (e) {
      // Saving error
    }
}
```

here is the full code

```js
export default function App() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');
  const [keys, setKeys] = useState('');

  // Async storage for input1

  const storeData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch (e) {
      // Saving error
    }
  }

  const getData = async (key) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
      if(value !== null) {
        // Value previously stored
        setInput1(value)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      // Error reading value
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => { 
    storeData(keys[keys.length-1],input1)
  },[input1])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>Text</Text>
        <Text>{'\n'}</Text>

        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setInput1(text);
            setKeys(prev=>[...prev,`input${keys.length}`])
          }
          value={input1}
          placeholder="Add text here"
        />

        <Text>{'\n'}</Text>

        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => setInput2(text)}
          value={input2}
          placeholder="Add text here"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. How do I assign this key parameter to my text inputs? And where else do I put it in my code? Thanks @uditkumar11

Comment: @Jay have a look now...

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to work. It'll just say "undefined" instead of saving the text I input. I tried this code in a project I'm making and I copied your code exactly. I will edit my post to show the code.

Comment: Hi @Jay, this snippet was just to give u an idea. Wrote a snippet to make it more clear. Live link: https://yvkf3.csb.app/, Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-moser-yvkf3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much @uditkumar11, I understand now!